# Install Windows 8 on separate partition for only system files

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, boot-partition

Essentialy, my main goal is to make my 24GB SSD only for system files, and my 500GB HDD for everything else, including as a default Program Files directory. How can I achieve this?

Will following [this guide](http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-change-system-partition-to-different-disk-in-windows-8) be the answer to my solution? Or is there something I have to do specifically in CMD during setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is an ideal scenario for a combo Intel Rapid Start and ExpressCache. Intel Rapid Start can boot up your Windows in 5-10 seconds, while Express Cache makes disk access much quicker. You may refer to this nifty guide to set up your PC.

http://community.acer.com/t5/Ultra-Thin/GUIDE-Install-ExpressCache-for-SSD-Caching/td-p/64381

Comment: Took me a while to fully understand the purpose of the hybrid, and why it uses IRS and the ExpressCache. The link you provided me helped, but it would have been ideal (small criticism...) if you had corrected my concept of a hybrid setup. My question posed the idea of storing bootfiles on the SSD, and everything else on the HDD. A hybrid setup is designed so ExpressCache independently dictates what files are stored on the SSD based on frequency of their access, and as you said, IRS speeds up read times (not sure how though). None the less though, you got the ball rolling for me!